# why does the width of the ancestor element become bigger when the float element is nested inside another float element in css

Tags: css

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
  div{
     border: 1px solid black;
     float: left;
  }

  p{
      border: 1px solid black;
      float: left;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
     text
     <p>text</p>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This is my code, why is the width of div become bigger and the 'text' inside the div seems off it's original space. I expect the width of div is the width of 'text'. **WHY** this will happen?

Comment: you have not set a width for the div, so it expands to it's content. You have floated the paragraph what changes it position from under the div text to left of the div text and the div adjusts to the new width and height. All works like expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="A">
  size
  <div class="B">
      will
      <div class="C">
          be increased
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

when you will add some tag inside another tag (like div, p) with all tag having (float: left) style attribute,  outer tag width will be increase by inner tag width..

but they will appear vertically as height is not fixed.. and width of div will remain increased size

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float: left;` of `p`

Regards.